# Displaying image in reportviewer

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am trying to display images in a Report Viewer control in C# Widnows application. The image datasource is set as External. If I have full path in the table field then it is working fine but If I have file name in the table field then I don't get the image.

File name only: deef2d72-e75a-41d4-8acd-086f7fe6aa89.bmp Full path: file:///C:\MyApp\Docs\deef2d72-e75a-41d4-8acd-086f7fe6aa89.bmp

I am trying the follwoing code but not working with file name only.

```
<code>


string st = Application.StartupPath + @"\\Docs\";
cmd = new SqlCommand ("select " + st + "[fileName] as fileName from documents where id=Id", cn);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file path has to be covered by single quote as it's a text in SQL syntax, so your code should be:

```
string st = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Docs");
st = @"file:///" + st;
cmd = new SqlCommand ("select '" + st + "\\' + [fileName] as fileName from documents where id=Id", cn);
```

And check if your SQL statement is like this when debugging:

```
select 'file:///D:\App\Admin\Admin\bin\Debug\Docs\' + [fileName] as fileName from documents where id=Id
```